# C histogram of words printing problems

Tags: c, printing, histogram

I have this code, what i want it to do is print the string that represents the word, and print the number of times it occurred in the file, instead it outprints something liek this: (a load of blank space) and then this number -1076720020, which i have no idea where it came from, how would i go about fixing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct podatki {
    char beseda[1000];
    int frekvenca;
};

void zamenjaj(char *str1, char *str2) {
   char *beseda2 = (char *)malloc((strlen(str1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(beseda2, str1);
   strcpy(str1, str2);
   strcpy(str2, beseda2);
   free(beseda2);
} 


int posodobi(struct podatki s[], const char unit[], int count) {
    int i =0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(s[i].beseda, unit) == 0) {
            s[i].frekvenca++;
            return count;
        }
    }
    strcpy(s[count].beseda, unit);
    s[count].frekvenca++;
    return (count + 1);
}




int main() {
    int stBes;
    scanf("%d", &stBes);
    //zacetne deklaracije
    struct podatki s[1000];
    char string[1000], unit[2000], c;
    int i = 0;
    int frekvenca = 0; 
    int j = 0; 
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;
    //branje 
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       s[i].frekvenca = 0;
    }

    i = 0;
    do {
       fflush(stdin);
       c = getchar();
       string[i++] = c;
    } while (c != '\n');


   //pretvori v majhne crke
   char *p;
   for (p = string; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
        *p = tolower(*p);
   }

   string[i - 1] = '\0';

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        while (i < strlen(string) && string[i] != ' ' &&  !ispunct(string[i])) {
       unit[j++] = string[i++];
    }
    if (j != 0) {
        unit[j] = '\0';
        count = posodobi(s, unit, count);
        j = 0;
    }
}

int a;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < count; ++j) {
        if (s[i].frekvenca < s[j].frekvenca) {
            a =  s[i].frekvenca;
            s[i].frekvenca = s[j].frekvenca;
            s[j].frekvenca = a;
            zamenjaj(s[i].beseda, s[j].beseda);

        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < count; j++) {
        if (s[i].frekvenca == s[j].frekvenca){
            if (strcmp(s[i].beseda, s[j].beseda) < 0) {
                a =  s[i].frekvenca;
                s[i].frekvenca = s[j].frekvenca;
                s[j].frekvenca = a;
                zamenjaj(s[i].beseda, s[j].beseda);
            }
        }
    }
}

//printanje
for (i = 0; i < stBes; i++) {
    printf("%s\t   %d\n", s[i].beseda, s[i].beseda);
    if (s[i].frekvenca > 1) {
        num++;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: First problem `fflush(stdin);` -> undefined behavior. And this `while (i < strlen(string)` is a very bad thing to do, since `strlen()` computes the length of the string, so you are doing an operation that gives the same result multiple times.

Comment: Your stack is over 1 million bytes large, on Windows the default stack size if one single megabyte so if you're on Windows you're dangerously close to the limit of the stack.

Comment: [Obligatory warning about casting the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I also see you using the `beseda`  array from the structure a lot, and it seems to me that there are cases you use the array before it's initialized. That will of course lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: And to *really* find the source of your problem, you should really run the program in a debugger, and step through it line by line to see that it does what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you convert the string to lower case before `nul` terminating it.

Here

```
i = 0;
do {
   fflush(stdin);
   c = getchar();
   string[i++] = c;
} while (c != '\n');
/* Goes here            <---------------------+ */
                      /*                      | */
//pretvori v majhne crke                      | */
char *p;              /*                      | */
for (p = string; *p != '\0'; ++p) {/*         | */
     *p = tolower(*p);/*                      | */
}                     /*                      | */
                      /*                      | */
string[i - 1] = '\0'; /* ---------------------+ */
```

You should also remove the `fflush(stdin)` and instead use `getchar()` to fetch the white space characters ignored by the previous `scanf()`, and please use `scanf()` correctly and check it's returned value.

Comment: Because you are overflowing the stack as @JoachimPileborg said, why are your buffers so large? did you think that memory had no limits?